# What is the largest web form created using Orbeon?

Tags: performance, orbeon

I'm keen to discover the maximum performance capabilities of Orbeon. I have worked on some very large forms which cause to become very sluggish when loading, publishing and navigating from section to section.

There is usually a tendency to chuck loads of fields and sections on to a form with little regard how the form and backend processing will operate. It would be interesting to know the largest form which Orbeon can handle with no degradation in performance.  It may be that some of our large forms can be broken up into several smaller forms.

Also, when I say form, I mean all the web services, external components and front-end form controls which come together to deliver the performance.

Comment: I am curious to know how many fields you have and what kind of processing times you are seeing.

Comment: From about 200-400 fields, plus several web services to dynamically create tables and populate dropdown select controls.

Comment: Number of fields is reasonable. I would suspect that particularly slow load times might be related to lots of service calls.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what's the largest one, but we routinely see forms with several hundreds of fields and dozens of sections and grids.

I would say that at this point performance tends to be roughly proportional to the complexity of the form: the more controls, the larger the form definition, the longer the time it takes to load and process.